# Parameter induction with std::variant

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, generic-programming, std

Recenty I am working on an *ORM* which accepts registration of functions by doing the following:

```
orm->register_func("NAME", &User::set_name);
```

So basically when the database returns the column `NAME`, the *ORM* will use the function `set_name` in `User`. During the development I learned more about `std::variant` and here is a little example of how I use it:

```
template<typename RET, typename T, typename ...Args>
using FPTR = RET(T::*)(Args...);

template<typename T>
using VARIANT_FPTR = std::variant<FPTR<void, T, const char *>, FPTR<void, T, const unsigned int>, long int>;
```

`FPTR` is basically a *generic function pointer* (assuming that the function is a class member) and `VARIANT_FPTR` defines the possibilities of functions I can register in the *ORM*.

Now, I have a problem due to the `std::variant` type. Here is the `register_func` implementation:

```
void register_func(std::string name, VARIANT_FPTR<T> ptr)
{
   _map.insert(std::make_pair(name, ptr));
}
```

However, I get a compilation error since a parameter like `&User::set_name` is not of type `std::variant`.

**Is there a way to make the `register_func` induce the type of its parameter? 
If not is there another way to make a similar process?**

The compilation error is:

```
error: cannot convert ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘VARIANT_FPTR<services::User>’ {aka ‘std::variant<void (services::User::*)(const char*), void (services::User::*)(unsigned int), long int>’}
```

Here is the map definition:

```
template<typename T>  class Orm
{
private:
   std::map<std::string, VARIANT_FPTR<T>> _map;
   // ...
};
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you are calling the register_func, and what is the exact error that you are getting? You may need to explicitly construct the variant like this: `VARIANT_FPTR<T>(&User::set_name)`

Comment: I call the register_func exactly as I show on the first piece of code and I edit the post to show the error.

Comment: The code is generated so unfortunately I can't pass generic to the function set_name. So basically the main should be: `int main()
{
 Orm<User> orm{};
 orm.register_func("NAME", &User::set_name);
 orm.register_func("NAME", &User::set_name);
 return 0;
}`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation however the set_name function is generated which means that I can't really do that. No other way right ?

Comment: @JeJo Since I can't have a template on the set_name function, it doesn't solve my issue ...

Comment: @ClémentJean Then you can write a helper template function to get the correct overload from the class. Like this: https://godbolt.org/z/4T3T4g. And here is the example code without the test: https://godbolt.org/z/-MArdf. If that's solved the issue, I can update the answer with that!

Comment: Just to confirm the significance of the error message, `User::set_name` *is* overloaded, right?

Comment: @DavisHerring no it's not, User is a generated class (Protobuf). I do not override that function

Comment: @ClémentJean: No—I said “overloaded”, like GCC did.

Comment: @DavisHerring I don't really know ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently parameter induction with std::variant is not always feasible in this kind of tricky case. So to solve this problem I finally decided to make the usage of register function a little bit more verbose. Here it is:

```
template<typename RES, typename CLASS, typename ...Args>
void register_func(std::string name, FPTR<RES, CLASS, Args...> ptr) {
   _map.insert(std::make_pair(name, ptr));
}
```

thus to use it you need to write:

```
orm->register_func<void, Class, const char *>("name", &Class::set_name);
```

### Interesting fact

I found out that some of the parameter can actually be inducted in some cases. In the case of the following function:

```
void Class::set_id(unsigned long id)
```

I apparently can just call the register_function like this:

```
orm->register_func("id", &Class::set_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the exact type in the instantiation of the `std::map` template. For instance, if you need `User` 's member functions in it, you need the following:

```
std::map<std::string, VARIANT_FPTR<User>> _map;
//                                 ^^^^^
```

Following is a complete minimal working example: **[See live online](https://godbolt.org/z/Em3REq)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct User
{
    template<typename T>
    void set_name(T)
    {}
};

template<typename RET, typename T, typename ...Args>
using FPTR = RET(T::*)(Args...);

template<typename T>
using VARIANT_FPTR = std::variant<FPTR<void, T, const char*>, FPTR<void, T, const unsigned int>, long int>;


template<typename T> class Orm
{
private:
    std::map<std::string, VARIANT_FPTR<T>> _map;

public:
    void register_func(std::string name, VARIANT_FPTR<User> ptr)
    {
        _map.emplace(name, ptr);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Orm<User> orm{};
    orm.register_func("NAME", &User::set_name<const char*>);
    orm.register_func("NAME", &User::set_name<const unsigned int>);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The map is actually in a generic class providing this T, so do I still need to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue (assuming that the compiler is correct in saying that the member function in question is overloaded) is that `std::variant<X,Y>` does *not* have constructors accepting `X` and `Y`.  Instead, it has a constructor **template** that performs overload resolution to determine which alternative to construct.  That template cannot deduce a simple `T` from a pointer (or pointer-to-member) to an unknown member of an an overload set.  In the case where only one of the overloads is suitable for any of the variant’s choices, you can simply **provide** those overloads yourself:

```
template<class T>
auto pick(FPTR<void, T, const char *> f) {return f;}
auto pick(FPTR<void, T, const unsigned int> f) {return f;}

/* elsewhere */ {
  orm->register_func("NAME", pick(&User::set_name));
}
```

If that’s still ambiguous, you can use `static_cast` to **choose** the overload:

```
orm->register_func
  ("NAME",
   static_cast<FPTR<void, T, const char *>>
     (&User::set_name));
```